# How do i a get a process window name and maintitlename by using the window handle or id?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a button click event
IEnumerable res;

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
var windows = FindWindowsWithText("GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2");
GetWindowThreadProcessId(windows,out res)
```

Then FindWindowsWithText

```
public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> FindWindowsWithText(string titleText)
        {
            return FindWindows(delegate(IntPtr wnd, IntPtr param)
            {
                return GetWindowText(wnd).Contains(titleText);
            });
        }
```

Then in the variable windows i'm getting one count in this case and the handle number:
[0] = 3343352

With this number 3343352 i need to find in the end the process in this case external process name and process mainwindowtitle.

Using this

```
IEnumerable<IntPtr> res;
```

Not sure if it's any good i thought to get the id and then somehow using the id to get the name and mainwindowtitle. I made a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `process = Process.GetProcessById(id)` to get the process by the ID. Then you can use `process.MainWindowTitle` and `process.ProcessName`.

Comment: @HaimShabort Maybe you are looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13547659/1218281